# How to install backstretch js in anjular4 project using angular cli?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, typescript

I have problem installing jquery backstretch in angular project using angular cli.I used "bower install ng-backstretch" as the command to install backstretch and its not working.

Comment: Did you defined it into angular-cli.json also along with jquery ???if yes then is it giving any error in console or not ??

Comment: but the command that i wrote on the command promt is not working

Comment: you tried with this right   "bower install ng-backstretch"

Comment: Read npm docs for installation guide [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-backstretch).

Comment: Yes the same one

Comment: what **error** you getting tell .